# How to calculate timestamp difference in sequence python

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

my DF looks like this:

```
0   2021-01-01 01:00:00+ 00:00
1   2021-01-01 01:05:00+ 00:00
2   2021-01-01 01:10:00+ 00:00
3   2021-01-01 01:15:00+ 00:00
4   2021-01-04 06:00:00+ 00:00
5   2021-01-04 06:05:00+ 00:00
```

This column is a timestamp. I want to calculate a duration of each period (without gaps between rows bigger than 5 minutes), its beginning and ending. For example here, I want to get as a results:

- 15 minutes from  2021-01-01 01:00:00+ 00:00 till 2021-01-01 01:15:00+
  00:00
- 5 minutes from 2021-01-04 06:00:00+ 00:00 till 2021-01-04
  06:05:00+ 00:00

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could use a custom group and `agg`:

```
# ensure datetime if string
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+ 00:00')

# compute a custom group for consecutive values within 5min
group = df['timestamp'].diff().gt('5min').cumsum()

# aggregate
out = (df
 .groupby(group)['timestamp']
 .agg(**{'start': 'min', 'end': 'max', 'delta': lambda g: g.max()-g.min()})
)
```

output:

```
                        start                 end           delta
timestamp                                                        
0         2021-01-01 01:00:00 2021-01-01 01:15:00 0 days 00:15:00
1         2021-01-04 06:00:00 2021-01-04 06:05:00 0 days 00:05:00
```